# Wordpress Theme and Plugin Integration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7, yoast

I have created a landing page theme for wordpress. Now I want to integrate plugin support to my theme.
How can I implement functionallity for these plugins?

- Yoast SEO
- Contact Form 7
- Mailchimp

I really need your help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yoast SEO

> You only need to have the `wp_head()` function called in the `<head>` tag in your `header.php`

2) Contact Form 7

> The best way to do this is to install the plugin, and then to style it properly. It will be best if you use the contact form 7 standard classes to match up with your design

3) Mailchimp

> You can use some plugins like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/). Then add one form and do the design.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the `wp_head()` function in your site's `<head>` and the `wp_footer()` function just before your closing `</body>` tag and these plugins should be supported by your theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer